# How do I handle a transactional scope in this situation?

Tags: c#, transactions, transactionscope, rollback

I haven't worked much with transaction scoping and I want to make sure that I'm approaching this idea correctly before I jump in too deeply.

### The Setup / Goal

- I have a list of items that are files to be copied to a remote system.
- For each file in that list, I need to create a transaction to:

  - Copy the file to a remote system
  - Make a call to a web service to add a reference to that new file to a database.
- If either the web service call or the file copy fail, I need to roll both actions back.

  - Rolling back the file copy will mean deleting the file on the remote system.
  - Rolling back the web service action will mean calling a different web service method to delete the entry I just made.
- If any of the items in the list of items fail, I'd like to return a message of some kind, but not stop the other items from being committed.

### What I'm Considering Doing

In my (quite limited) reading on the topic, I think this might be the proper approach:

- Create a Resource Manager for file copies that allows it to participate in durable transactions
- Create a Resource Manager for the web service call along the same lines
- Create a foreach loop for each item in the list
- For each item, create a transaction scope that uses the two resource managers and rolls back / reports if something goes wrong.

### The Question(s)

- Is there anything I'm not seeing here or a new methodology I should be implementing, or is this actually the way to go?

### Resources So Far

As I examine the problem and try to wrap my head around it, these are some of the pages I'm perusing:

- [Implementing a Resource Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229975%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) [MSDN]
- [Enlisting Resources as participants in a transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172153%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) [MSDN]
- [Implementing an Implicit Transaction using TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818746.aspx) [MSDN]

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: How about flowing the transaction to the web service instead of creating the web service as a resource? This will be possible only when the service is a WCF service and implementing a proper binding which supports transactions flow. Not very sure if this will be a viable solution for you though.

Comment: Hi samar, that's a great idea and normally something I'd pursue, but in the context of my current project (and schedule) it unfortunately isn't an option.